Can we write the eigenvalues of $\begin{pmatrix}l & 0\\ 0 & l^{-1}\end{pmatrix}M$ in terms of that of $M\in\operatorname{SL}_2(q),l\in\Bbb F_q$?
The Question:
Can we write the eigenvalues of $\begin{pmatrix}l & 0\\ 0 & l^{-1}\end{pmatrix}M$ in terms of that of $M\in\operatorname{SL}_2(q),l\in\Bbb F_q$?
Thoughts:
Let $L=\begin{pmatrix}
l & 0\\
0 & l^{-1}
\end{pmatrix}$. Let $M=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}\in\operatorname{SL}_2(q)$ have eigenvalues $\lambda,\lambda^{-1}\in\Bbb F_q$.
Then, since $ad-bc=1$,
$$\begin{align}
\det(M-xI)&=\begin{vmatrix}
a-x & b\\
c & d-x
\end{vmatrix}\\
&=x^2-(a+d)x+1
\end{align}$$
implies (for $q$ odd) WLOG
$$\lambda=\frac{a+d+\sqrt{(a+d)^2-4}}{2}.$$
Similarly, the eigenvalues of $LM$ are thus
$$\mu_{1,2}=\frac{l a+l^{-1}d\pm\sqrt{(la+l^{-1}d)^2-4}}{2}.\tag{1}$$
I know $\mu_1\mu_2=1$.
Expanding out $\mu_1$ in $(1)$:
$$\mu_1=\frac{la+l^{-1}d+\sqrt{l^2a^2+ad+l^{-2}d^2-4}}{2}.$$
That's all I have so far.
I have nothing for $q$ even.

Consider the following. If $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2=1/\lambda_1$ happen to be elements of $\Bbb{F}_q$, and distinct from each other, they determine $M$ up to conjugacy. It is morally certain that when we multiply a conjugacy class from the left by $L$, the resulting matrices will fall into several distinct conjugacy classes, most of the time characterized by different pairs of eigenvalues $(\mu_1,\mu_2)$. Based on that alone, I would never suspect/hope there to be a simple relation. If I come up with an illuminating family, I will post it.

I don't see how that is possible in general.
Suppose that $M$ has eigenvalues $\alpha, \alpha^{-1}\in\mathbb{F}_q$. This occurs for the matrices $M_1:=\begin{bmatrix}\alpha & 0\\0&\alpha^{-1}\end{bmatrix}$, $M_2:=\begin{bmatrix}\alpha^{-1} & 0\\0&\alpha\end{bmatrix}$. But the eigenvalues of $LM_1$ are $l\alpha$ and $l^{-1}\alpha^{-1}$, whereas those of $LM_2$ are $l^{-1}\alpha$ and $l\alpha^{-1}$. Just knowing $l$, $\det M$ and $\rm{tr}\ M$ does not let you distinguish these possibilities.

Thank you. I will leave the question open for a while before accepting this. Who knows?  There might be a really clever way to do it.
